# what is ... in typescript programming?

Tags: typescript

In typescript classes and 3rd party library I have seen `...` and I am wondering how to use it.

Below is one example from ng2-admin template. I think its used to import the whole json from that class.

```
export const PAGES_MENU = [
  {
    path: 'pages',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        data: {
          menu: {
            title: 'Dashboard',
            icon: 'ion-android-home',
            selected: false,
            order: 0
          }
        }
      },
      {
        path: 'editors',
        data: {
          menu: {
            title: 'Editors',
            icon: 'ion-edit',
            order: 100,
          }
        }
      }
   ]
 }
];


//use
import { PAGES_MENU } from './pages/pages.menu';

export const MENU = [
  ...PAGES_MENU
];
```

I think here it import whole json and export them for use.\ in different classes.

Answer (score 2):

`...` is the [ES2015 Spread Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

> The spread syntax allows an expression to be expanded in places where multiple arguments (for function calls) or multiple elements (for array literals) or multiple variables  (for destructuring assignment) are expected.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Answer (score 1):

In your example it's called the [spread operator](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/spread-operator.html), but `...` could also be the [rest operator](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/rest-parameters.html).

```
function foo(x, ...y:number[]) { } // This is the rest operator, see below
var args = [0, 1, 2];

// Instead of doing this
foo("hello", args[0], args[1], args[2])

//You can do this
foo("hello", ...args); // This calls foo like foo("hello", 0, 1, 2)

// The function call gets compiled to this javascript:
foo.apply(void 0, ["hello"].concat(args));
```

In typescript it's mostly used together with the rest operator, otherwise you'll have some type errors:

```
function foo(x, y, z) { }
var args = [0, 1, 2];

// Type error here
foo(...args)

// But you could get around it by:
(foo as any)(...args)
```

The rest operator lets you define a function that can take any number of arguments. And when you have those, the spread operator is convenient if you already have the arguments in an array.

The usage in you example gets compiled to a regular slice:

```
exports.MENU = PAGES_MENU.slice();
```

Comment: So its a JavaScript operator not typescript special.

Comment: @AniruddhaDas It's defined in ES2015, and TypeScript handles it as well.

Answer (score 1):

It's the spread operator. And it's not only available in typescript but also in ES2015 javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Answer (score 1):

This is the [`spread syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator#Copy_an_array) which is here used to (shallow) copy an array.

In your case the following expressions are giving the same results:

```
[...PAGES_MENU]

PAGES_MENU.slice()

Array.from(PAGES_MENU)

PAGES_MENU.map(x => x)
```